# Find problem with Nautilus plugin Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome, nautilus, syslog

syslog gets this warning message every couple of seconds.

```
** (nautilus:2405): WARNING **: Unexpected plugin response. This probably indicates a bug in a Nautilus extension
```

How do I trace the cause/source?

(Doesn't matter if Nautilus is run from terminal, Cairo Dock or Ubuntu launcher.  FYI, for now, I've created a gnome-session.conf file in /etc/rsyslog.d which simply causes all 'warning' priority messages from gnome-session to be thrown away. It still would be nice to find the source of the problem.)

Comment: How did you run nautilus, from the terminal?